# MPI_Scatterv not returning any values to the recvbuf

Tags: c++, mpi

I'm trying to implement a parallel quicksort algorithm. Unfortunately, I'm having some issues simply distributing my data. For some reason, my `list` vectors aren't being populated after calling the `MPI_Scatterv()` function.

I'm not incredibly familiar with C++ or pointers in general, so I have a sneaking suspicion that my buffers might be the issue. The backbone of the code comes from [here](https://gist.github.com/ehamberg/1263868).

The actual code:

```
// n-dimensional hypercube quicksorting program

#include <mpi.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>       /* clock_t, clock, CLOCKS_PER_SEC */

using namespace std;

vector<int> parseInput(string _file);
void parseOutput(vector<int> _content, string _file);
void quickSort(vector<int>& a, int first, int last);
int pivot(vector<int>& a, int first, int last);
void swap(int& a, int& b);
string dec2bin(unsigned n);
int bin2dec(string s);

int main (int argc, char *argv[]){
    int rank, rank2, tasks;     // for storing this process' rank, and the number of processes
    int * sendcounts;    // array describing how many elements to send to each process
    int * displs;        // array describing the displacements where each segment begins

    int rem;                     // elements remaining after division among processes
    int sum = 0;                // Sum of counts. Used to calculate displacements

    clock_t t;          // timekeeping variable 

    vector<int> lists, list, l1, l2, c;
    string id, id2;
    int pivot;
    int d, x;

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &tasks);
    MPI_Status *status;
    MPI_Request request;

    // the data to be distributed
    lists = parseInput("input.txt");

    // Allocating memory for the receiving buffers to a large engouh size to accomodate any incoming message.
    list.reserve(lists.size()/tasks);
    l1.reserve(lists.size()/tasks);
    l2.reserve(lists.size()/tasks);
    c.reserve(lists.size()/tasks);

    sendcounts = (int*) malloc(tasks * sizeof(int));
    displs = (int*) malloc(tasks * sizeof(int));

    // calculate send counts and displacements
    for (int i = 0; i < tasks; i++){
        sendcounts[i] = (lists.size())/tasks;
        rem =(lists.size())%tasks;
        if (rem > 0) {
            sendcounts[i]++;
            rem--;
        }

        displs[i] = sum;
        sum += sendcounts[i];
    }

    // print calculated send counts and displacements for each process
    if (0 == rank) {
        for (int i = 0; i < tasks; i++) {
            printf("sendcounts[%d] = %d\tdispls[%d] = %d\n", i, sendcounts[i], i, displs[i]);
        }
    }

    // divide the data among processes as described by sendcounts and displs
    MPI_Scatterv(&lists[0], sendcounts, displs, MPI_INT, &list[0], lists.size()/tasks, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    cout << id << ": " << list.size() << endl;

    MPI_Finalize();

    free(sendcounts);
    free(displs);

    return 0;
}
```

The code for `parseInput()` takes a .txt file with integers seperated by new lines and returns a vector:

```
vector<int> parseInput(string _file){
    string filename = _file;
    vector<int> numbers;
    int number;

    ifstream inputFile(filename.c_str());

    if(inputFile){
        while(inputFile >> number){
            numbers.push_back(number);
        }
    } else {
        cout << "There was an error opening the file.";
    }

    inputFile.close();

    return numbers;
}
```

I've been wracking my brain for hours now, all it does is return empty vectors. Honestly, any help at all would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you add a sample input.txt to your question?

Comment: This is looks like a simple problem easily solved by stepping through the code in a debugger. Did you try that? Why not? Please help us to help you.

Comment: Another thought: if nothing is pushed on the vector and there was no error message then the while was executed and the next line was not. Therefore the first data read from the file was invalid. White space? Real numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on this code, I'm not sure what your `MPI_Scatterv` call is supposed to be doing. It looks like you're trying to read in your data, then distribute it to all of the processes in the job via the `MPI_Scatterv` function. However, it also looks like all of the processes are actually reading in the data from the file so there's no real reason for the `MPI_Scatterv` call.

You might want to restructure your code to ensure that either:

1. Only rank 0 is reading the data and then distributing it to all of the processes. Or...
2. Everyone is reading the data and they can just pick out which part is important to them.

If you choose #1, make sure that you populate the recvcount variable correctly. **If everyone doesn't have access to `lists.size()`, then that will cause an issue.**

Comment: You're completely right. I just went with solution #2, make my life simpler.